# laravel 4 swiftmailer library CC recipient received double dots / period

Tags: laravel-4, swiftmailer

I am using Laravel Mail Library as it is stated it is using swiftmailer library.
This is problem that they having in github as below:
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/252

But how do I fix this in Laravel, how do it do the setting, anyone?

Below is the coding happen to have double dots, it is at the extension part there. You may refer to line 94 from the below full code.

```
<td width="26" valign="top"><img src="http://pts.locahost.com/img/email/left_description_ribbon.png" width="26" height="28" alt="left_ribbon" /></td>
```

This is the full code of the email content, please have a try

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Ticket</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; }
    .ExternalClass { width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; }
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
    html { width: 100%; }
    body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; }
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    table { border-spacing: 0; }
    img { display: block !important; }
    table td { border-collapse: collapse; }
    .yshortcuts a { border-bottom: none !important; }
    a { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }
    /*space*/
    td[class="space2"] { display: none !important; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        body { width: auto !important; }
        table[class="table600"] { width: 440px !important; }
        table[class="table540"] { width: 87% !important; float: none !important; }
        table[class="table2-2"] { width: 45% !important; height: auto !important; }
        img[class="img1"] { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
        td[class="QuoteTitle"] { width: 100% !important; font-size: 18px !important; }
        table[class="social"] { width: 100px !important; }
        table[class="table1-3"] { width: 30% !important; }
        table[class="table1-3color"] { width: 30% !important; }
        table[class="table3-1"] { width: 70% !important; }
        /*space*/
        table[class="space"] { display: none !important; }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        body { width: auto !important; }
        table[class="table600"] { width: 270px !important; }
        table[class="table540"] { width: 87% !important; float: none !important; }
        table[class="table2-2"] { width: 100% !important; text-align: center !important; }
        img[class="img1"] { width: 100% !important; }
        td[class="QuoteTitle"] { font-size: 19px !important; }
        table[class="table1-3"] { width: 100% !important; }
        table[class="table1-3color"] { width: 100% !important; background: #f8f8f8; border-bottom: 2px solid #000000 !important; }
        table[class="table3-1"] { width: 100% !important; }
        /*space*/
        table[class="space"] { display: none !important; }
        span[class="space"] { padding: 10px !important; }
        td[class="space"] { display: block !important; }
        td[class="space2"] { display: block !important; }
        td[class="space3"] { display: none !important; }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#d6d0c6">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#d6d0c6">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table class="table600" width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">                  
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border:3px solid #747474;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;"><table class="table600" width="590" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-top:1px solid #747474;border-left:1px solid #747474; border-right:1px solid #747474; border-bottom:1px solid #747474;">

                            <!--Header-->
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="10"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><table class="table540" width="540" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="space3" width="120" valign="top"><table width="120" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table540">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="25px" style="border-bottom:2px solid #d4d4d4;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                                <td width="40" valign="top"></td>
                                                <td width="222" valign="top"><table width="222" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                                                    <!--Logo-->

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="middle"><img class src="http://pts.localhost.com/img/logo.png" width="186"  alt="logo" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="20" align="center" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <!--little description-->

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#565656;"><table width="222" height="28" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width="26" valign="top"><img src="http://pts.localhost.com/img/email/left_description_ribbon..png" width="26" height="28" alt="left_ribbon" /></td>
                                                                <td width="170" valign="top"><table width="170" height="20" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#8d8c8c">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td height="20" align="center" valign="middle" style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#ffffff;">Printing Tracking System</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table></td>
                                                                <td width="26" valign="top"><img src="http://pts.localhost.com/img/email/right_description_ribbon.png" width="26" height="28" alt="right_ribbon" /></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                                <td width="40" valign="top"></td>
                                                <td class="space3" width="120" valign="top"><table width="120" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table540">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="25px" style="border-bottom:2px solid #d4d4d4;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="10"></td>
                                    </tr>                                   

                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                            <!--End Header--> 


                            <!--Calendar-->

                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-top:1px dashed #e0e0e0;"><table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="30" valign="top"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top"><table class="table540" width="540" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr valign="top">
                                                <td ><table class="table1-3" width="120" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="120" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table1-3color">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:50px; font-weight: bold; color:#8d8c8c">25</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:27px;color:#555353; font-weight:bold;">NOV</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px;color:#555353; font-weight:bold;">09:25:26</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="15" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>

                                                <!--Space-->

                                                <table width="1" height="100" class="space" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style=" border-left:2px solid #d4d4d4;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse: collapse;"><p style="padding-left: 17px;">&nbsp;</p></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>

                                                <!--End Space-->

                                                <table width="400" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table3-1">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size:18px; color:#555353;">ALLIANCE STORAGE MEDIA SDN BHD<br />Status: Transfer Stock</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="15" valign="top"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style=" font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#999999; line-height:22px;">Action: Take out the stock from Warehouse, check quantity and model.<br />Remark: cvncvn<br />Updated by: Ken Teo<br />Create by: Ken Teo<br />Order Date: 2013-11-22<br />Print Quantity: 100<br />Total Quantity: 100<br />Product: PenDrive SLIQ 2.0 - 4GB<br />Packaging Design: Paper Box Series<br />Printer: Ah Fatt<br /><br /><a href="http://pts.localhost.com/ticket/44">click here for ticket info</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="35" valign="top"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>

                            <!--End Calendar--> 


                            <!--Quote-->
                                                        <!--End Quote--> 
                            </table></td>
                        </tr>                       
                        <tr>
                            <td height="20"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: From the bug report it looks like it's a mail server issue, the script is working fine. "Check why your mail server does not respect RFC"

Comment: I tested with three mail server (gmail, mailgun, my shared hosting) with same outcome!, the same content I send to "To" and "CC", the recipient for the "To" user, does not have this issue, it only happen to "CC" user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved due to the bug in swiftmailer.
Thank you xdecock for fixing the bug.

Detail can be view from here.
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/pull/401